# MySQL: Using DATE_SUB to subtract business days instead of all calendar days

Tags: mysql

I am looking for a robust solution to subtract the number of business days from a date. I am using DATE_SUB however it subtracts all calendar days.

For example, if today is Monday and I subtract 2 days from today, I would like for the result to be Thursday last week and not Saturday.

Comment: Create a calendar table.

Comment: How would you use this calendar table to achieve the result? I am after a function which provides a robust solution.

Comment: Did you search at all? http://stackoverflow.com/a/1829033

Answer (score -2):

You can use DAYOFWEEK to calculate the right number of days to subtract based on that. This also works for date_add. For the DAYOFWEEK index, 1 is equal to Sunday and 2 is equal to to Monday.

```
case 
when DAYOFWEEK({date}) = 1 then date_sub({date}, Interval 2 Day)
when DAYOFWEEK({date}) = 2 then date_sub({date}, Interval 3 Day)
else date_sub({date}, Interval 1 Day)
end
```

http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-dayofweek-function.php

Comment: Official holidays that don't fall on Saturdays or Sundays are non-business days. In some countries Sundays are business days. And you probably should link to official documentation instead of some click-bait site.